# cloud9 MySQL error : command not found

Tags: mysql

I am a novice in programming and I think I set up MySQL environment properly within cloud9(including installing and 
But whenever I run the code the terminal shows me no command found. 
How should I solve this? Thanks for reading my post.

```
CREATE TABLE flights (id VARCHAR(20), carrier VARCHAR(20), distance VARCHAR(20));

EXPLAIN SELECT id 
FROM flights AS f
WHERE distance < ( SELECT AVG(distance) 
                   FROM flights
                   WHERE carrier = f.carrier);
```

Comment: you obviously would need to (start and then) use a `mysql` shell, not a `bash` shell. maybe try installing `phpMyAdmin`, in order to have some GUI available:
https://community.c9.io/t/setting-up-phpmyadmin/1723

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little ambiguous. Have you connected already to MySQL? Please add the complete error so people can help you here.

Also, look into this question and its answers for more information that may help you.
[php connect to mysql db in cloud 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19531822/php-connect-to-mysql-db-in-cloud-9#26986286)